# How to add content to an extra column in grid using ATK

Tags: atk4

I have a grid that gets its content from the `QuestionCollection` model.

In one column I want to show the questions in the collection. I use three models to connect questions to collections:

1. Question
2. QuestionInCollection
3. QuestionCollection

That is, I want to show content connected to specific rows in an extra column, which is added to the grid with `addColumn`. But how do I insert this content to each row?

I have tried using `setTemplate` and `setSource`, as well as extending the `QuestionCollection` model with an extra 'question' field. But I cannot get it to work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is an example of code:

```
$q=$this->api->db->dsql()->table('questionincollection')->join('question')->field('question.name as question');
$rows=$q->getAll();
$quest=$crud->grid->addColumn('text','question')->setSource($rows);
```

But this one set the source for the whole grid, not just the column as I wanted it to.

Another way: Trying to add a template and filling in content - but how do I connect content for each row to $questions?

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $question=array_values($row);
  $questions[]=array_pop($question);
}
#Plan: To implode questions into each row...
$quest=$crud->grid->addColumn('template','question','Spørgsmål')->setTemplate('<?$questions?> ');
```

Comment: Please show some of your code, for example the approaches you mention in the last paragraph.

Comment: I did that now, hope it clarifies what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found out myself using this page: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/modeltable/expression and mysql Group_Concat.

This model gets information from questionincollection and question and put all questions in a collection into the same cell in the grid. So simple, once you know how to do it ;-)

```
<?php
class Model_QuestionCollection extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='questioncollection';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
        $this->hasMany('QuestionInCollection');
        $this->add('dynamic_model/Controller_AutoCreator');

        $this->addExpression('questionsincollection')->type('html')->set(function($model,$select)use($self){
          return $model->refQuestions($select->getField('id')) ->dsql->join('question','question_id')->field($select->expr('GROUP_CONCAT(question.name SEPARATOR "<br>") questions '));
      });

    }
    function refQuestions($id=null){
    return $this->add('Model_QuestionInCollection')
      ->addCondition('questioncollection_id',$id?:$this->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: was about to suggest exactly that :) great job finding this.

Comment: yeah, this is very nice example.